# Is it possible to create an instance and cast back to generic interface type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following interface and classes in my project

```
public interface IProcessor<T> : where T:IGenericData
{ 
   void Process(T data);
} 


public class CompanyADataProcessor : IProcessor<CompanyAData>
{
   void Process(CompanyAData Data);
}
```

*CompanyAData implements the IGenericData.*

I would like to achieve the following cast, is it possible? 
         `(IProcessor<IGenericData>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CompanyADataProcessor));`

**Update**

I think I am fully cleared about why this won't work. I guess I need to change my design in order to solve my current problem.

Basically, my current issue is we have a data file processor, each client has a different data schema, some of client data required extra clean up, reformatting etc before saving into our database, that's one of the reason why I started to separate Processor class to deal with specific client data.

The current logic is first initiating all the processors from the config custom section, therefore, if we have a new client has different data,we can easily create a new processor, throw the dll to the bin folder without restart the application.

```
 <Processors>
  <add  name="CompanyA" type="CompanyA.ThreeStepProcessor,CompanyA.Processor" outputPath="../../Output/CompanyA"/>
 .....
</Processors>
```

Comment: What happens if you try this? Is there any problem?

Comment: @CuongLe, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. If it were, then you could pass that interface reference to some other code, and they could pass an instance of any arbitrary implementation of `IGenericData` to your `CompanyADataProcessor` class's `Process()` method, when it clearly expects only `CompanyAData` instances to be provided.

C# has support for variant generic interfaces, but even using that syntax would only allow a cast in the other direction, i.e. casting to `IProcessor<CompanyAData>` from `IProcessor<IGenericData>`, not the other way around. Given the interface you've shown, that's the only direction it would be type-safe.

Comment: `IProcessor<CompanyADataProcessor>` does not make any sense because `CompanyADataProcessor` alsready implements the interface. I think you mean `IProcessor<CompanyAData>` which is exactly what the OP asked for. So it IS possible.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: thanks...those were typos (now fixed). I do mean `IProcessor<CompanyAData>` as you said, but I also meant to write casting _to_ that interface from the other. That is, it's fine for some caller to pass an instance of `CompanyAData` to an implementation that can handle any `IGenericData` object, but not vice a versa.

Comment: @HimBromBeere No, the OP asked to cast to `IProcessor<IGenericData>` which is _not_ possible unless `IGenericData` is covariant.

Comment: @DStanley: to be clear, it's the `IProcessor` interface that would need to be covariant, not `IGenericData`.

Comment: @DStanley I only said it IS possible (ofc. if interface was covariant). The OP wants to cast a `CompanyADataProcessor` (which implements `IProcessor<CompanyAData>`) to `IProcessor<IGenericData>` which works by covariance.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: that would work _if_ the interface could be made covariant. But it can't be. It can only be made contravariant.

Answer (score 3):

Peter Duniho's answer is correct. You have the variance the wrong way. Your interface could be made *contravariant* ("`in`"), by saying:

```
public interface IProcessor<in T> ...
```

by that would only allow the opposite conversion of what you ask.

The semantic reason is that an `IProcessor<IGenericData>` is a processor that can process *any* `IGenericData`, while an `IProcessor<CompanyAData>` guarantees to process only `CompanyAData`.
There is no hope of making `IProcessor<T>` *covariant* (like `IProcessor<out T>`) since `T` is clearly used in an "`in`" context.

So (because any `CompanyAData` is an `IGenericData`):

> An `IProcessor<IGenericData>` is an `IProcessor<CompanyAData>`

but:

> An `IProcessor<CompanyAData>` is ***not*** an `IProcessor<IGenericData>`

This is what contravariance is all about.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CompanyADataProcessor` is an aptly-named processor of `CompanyAData`.  It takes `CompanyAData` as an input and processes it.  If you cast it to an `IProcessor<IGenericData>`, then now the *same object* is being asked to process *any* kind of generic data.  So no, the cast is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. What you can do is just use a sta way interface

```
(IProcessor<CompanyAData>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CompanyADataProcessor));
```

or use a method to create an instance stating the type

```
public T CreateInstance<T, TEntity>() 
    where T : IProcessor<TEntity>, new()
    where TEntity : IGenericData, new()
{
    return new T();
}

CreateInstance<CompanyADataProcessor, CompanyAData>();
```

Comment: I think that will work, however the CompanyADataProcessor assembly is stored in the config module, I can't determine what the concrete type of T during the instance creation.